# Failed asserting last controller used <"error"> was "index"

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I'm trying to run tests on Zend Framework 1 with PHPUnit. I can run the test but it gives me the error:

```
$ ./library/bin/phpunit tests/application/controllers/IndexControllerTest.php
PHPUnit 3.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/vhosts/qasystem/qasystem/phpunit.xml

F

Time: 3.38 seconds, Memory: 15.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) IndexControllerTest::testIndexAction
Failed asserting last controller used <"error"> was "index"

/var/www/vhosts/qasystem/qasystem/library/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php:1000
/var/www/vhosts/qasystem/qasystem/tests/application/controllers/IndexControllerTest.php:18

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

If it's throwing an error, how can I see what the error is? I have set application.ini to

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

...for that environment. If this were a browser I'd be able to see what the error/exception was on the screen. Is there anyway to see what the error is in PHPUnit in CLI? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework captures any errors  and displays the error message in the output.  So for this problem, after your dispatch command, `var_dump($this->getResponse()->outputBody()`.

Then when you rerun your tests, the html output that is being checked by Zend Framework will be output and you can see the error.  It will be a big wall-o-text but you will be able to see what the error is.